# Counter did not count user's correct answer in Flutter

Tags: flutter, loops, dart, math, counter

I'm doing a math quiz using Flutter, I also have 3 types of different questions that will contain 4 random questions.
I have 3 loops for each type of question, each loop will iterate 4 times with a counter that counts the user's answers and when the user finishes all questions (total =12), I will show the result like this for example:

Your score is 4 out of 4 in 'type of question' \n
Your score is 4 out of 4 in 'type of question' \n
Your score is 4 out of 4 in 'type of question'

Here is the problem, the counter for loop#2 and loop#3 is not working right and is not returning the right score.

The code:

```
 final int numOfSingleQuestions = 4; 
  final int numOfTensQuestions = 4; 
  final int numOfHundredQuestions = 4; 

  void initState() {
    super.initState();

//question type 1 & the a list with the mcq
    for (var i = 1; i < numOfSingleQuestions + 1; i++) {
      ans = [];
      var x = Random().nextInt(9);
      var y = Random().nextInt(9);
      textDirection:
      TextDirection.rtl;
      qustions.add("$x  +  $y =  ...... ");
      answers.add(x + y);
      ansData = [
        x + y,
        x + y + Random().nextInt(9),
        x + y - Random().nextInt(9),
        x + y + Random().nextInt(9),
      ];

      for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        var rNum = Random().nextInt(ansData.length).round();
        ans.add(ansData[rNum]);
        ansData.removeAt(rNum);
      }
      mcq.add(ans);
    }

//question type 2 & the a list with the mcq
    for (var i = 1; i < numOfTensQuestions + 1; i++) {
      ans = [];
      var x = Random().nextInt(99);
      var y = Random().nextInt(99);
      qustions.add("$x  +  $y =  ...... ");
      answers.add(val1 + y);
      ansData = [
        x + y,
        x + y + Random().nextInt(99),
        x + y - Random().nextInt(99),
        x + y + Random().nextInt(99),
      ];

      for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        var rNum = Random().nextInt(ansData.length).round();
        ans.add(ansData[rNum]);
        ansData.removeAt(rNum);
      }
      mcq.add(ans);
    }

//question type 3 & the a list with the mcq
    for (var i = 1; i < numOfHundredQuestions + 1; i++) {
      ans = [];
      var x = Random().nextInt(999);
      var y = Random().nextInt(999);
      qustions.add("$x  +  $y =  ...... ");
      answers.add(val1 + y);
      ansData = [
        x + y,
        x + y + Random().nextInt(999),
        x + y - Random().nextInt(999),
        x + y + Random().nextInt(999),
      ];

      for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        var rNum = Random().nextInt(ansData.length).round();
        ans.add(ansData[rNum]);
        ansData.removeAt(rNum);
      }
      mcq.add(ans);
    }
  }

_changeQuestion(ans) {
    userAnswer.add(ans);
    if (j + 1 >= qustions.length) {

//count the score
      var Singlescore = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
        if (userAnswer[i].toString() == answers[i].toString()) {
          Singlescore++;
        }
      }

//count the score
      var Tensscore = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
        if (userAnswer[i].toString() == answers[i].toString()) {
          Tensscore++;
        }
      }

//count the score
      var Hundredscore = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
        if (userAnswer[i].toString() == answers[i].toString()) {
          Hundredscore++;
        }
      }
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => UserAnswer(
              maxSingleScore: numOfSingleQuestions,
              maxTensScore: numOfTensQuestions,
              maxHundredScore: numOfHundredQuestions,
              singlescore: Singlescore,
              tensscore: Tensscore,
              hundredscore: Hundredscore,
              answers: answers,
              qustions: qustions,
              userAnswer: userAnswer),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      print("called");
      setState(() {
        ++j;
        isMarked = false;
      });
    }
```

Here is when I tried to show the score to the user:

```
class UserAnswer extends StatelessWidget {
  final singlescore;
  final tensscore;
  final hundredscore;
  final maxSingleScore;
  final maxTensScore;
  final maxHundredScore;
  final List qustions;
  final List answers;
  final List userAnswer;

  UserAnswer(
      {this.singlescore,
      this.tensscore,
      this.hundredscore,
      this.maxSingleScore,
      this.maxTensScore,
      this.maxHundredScore,
      required this.qustions,
      required this.answers,
      required this.userAnswer});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
//needed widgets

        Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("Your score is \n",
                style: TextStyle(
                  decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                  fontSize: 25,
                  color: Color(0XFF1ea366),
                )),
            Text(
                "${singlescore.toString()} out of ${maxSingleScore.toString()} in singles",
                style: TextStyle(
                  decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                  fontSize: 25,
                  color: Color(0XFF1ea366),
                )),
            //SizedBox(height: 30),
            Text(
                "${tensscore.toString()} out of ${maxTensScore.toString()} in tens",
                style: TextStyle(
                  decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                  fontSize: 25,
                  color: Color(0XFF1ea366),
                )),
            // SizedBox(height: 30),
            Text(
                "${hundredscore.toString()} out of ${maxHundredScore.toString()} in hundreds",
                style: TextStyle(
                  decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                  fontSize: 25,
                  color: Color(0XFF1ea366),
                )),
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your code snippets are missing some crucial pieces of information because I am seeing some disconnect between where you define `mcq` and also where you are calling `_changeQuestion()`. It would also be helpful if you provided the output of loop#2 and loop#3. My initial thoughts from the code you provided is that you might be running into some scoping issues.

In your `_changeQuestion` method, you are looping through user answers but I'm not entirely sure how you are identifying the different types of questions. Essentially, your Singlescore, Tensscore, Hundredscore will all be the same value because there is nothing distinguishing the types.

I would try separating the answers into their own arrays.

```
userAnswersSingle[]
userAnswersTens[]
userAnswersHundreds[]
```

and then loop through these. Then if you need the total number of answers, you can either sum up the lengths or you can add a separate counter to keep track of user submissions.